# Color the row of a HTML table from a cell value (from an SQL server)

Tags: javascript, html, css, cell, background-color

I am trying to create a code which colors the row/line of a specific table depending on a cell`s value. The data comes from a Microsoft SQL server

For example:
if the cell named "files_link" is with a value 0 - color the whole line red (or if it is possible, color another row from that line red)

The idea is if the cell is:

0 - red color

1 - green color

2 - yellow

[image: The idea (half working code)]

Sadly I cannot add a working version in the code snippet because I am getting the data from an SQL server.

```js
$(function() {
    $('tr > td:odd').each(function(index) {
        var scale = [['no', 0], ['yes', 1]];
        var score = $(this).text();
        for (var i = 0; i < scale.length; i++) {
            if (score <= scale[i][1]) {
                $(this).addClass(scale[i][0]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 20em;
}

#score {
    width: 50%;
}

#name {
    width: 50%;
}

th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
}

th:nth-child(even),
td:nth-child(even) {
    text-align: center;
}

.yes {
    background-color: #b6d8b0;
}

.half {
    background-color: #ffc16f;
}

.no {
    background-color: #CC5959;
}
```

```html
<html>
<style>
td{text-align: center;}
.yes {
    background-color: #b6d8b0;
}

.half {
    background-color: #ffc16f;
}

.no {
    background-color: #CC5959;
}
</style>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jo.js"></script>
<title>AV.31.U</title>
</head>

<body>
<table style="width: 100%; height:50%" border="1" cellpadding="3">
<caption>AV.31.U</caption>
<tr>
            <td><div id="current_date"></p>
<script>
date = new Date();
year = date.getFullYear();
month = date.getMonth() + 1;
day = date.getDate();
document.getElementById("current_date").innerHTML = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
</script></td>
            <td colspan="6">Home</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
    <th>Проект
    <th>Машина
    <th>te
    <th>video_link
    <th>te
    <th>files_link
    <th>te
    <th>draw_link
</tr>
<?php
$username = 'censored';
$password = 'censored';
$servername = 'censored';
$database = 'censored';
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $db = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$servername;Database=$database;", $username, $password) or die ("could not connect<br />");

  $stmt = "Select * from machine";

  $result = odbc_exec($db, $stmt);

  if ($result == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $stmt<br />");

  while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) // while there are rows
  {
     print "<tr>\n";
     print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "project_ID") . "\n";
     print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "machine_project_ID") . "\n";
     print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "video_link") . "\n";
     print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "files_link") . "\n";
     print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "draw_link") . "\n";
     print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, 'has_draw') . "\n";
     print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "has_video") . "\n";
     print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "has_files") . "\n";
     print "</tr>\n";
  }

  odbc_free_result($result);

  odbc_close($db);
?>



</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add the rendered HTML to your question (show source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, place data in the `<tbody>` of the table. Second, dates can be formatted as Strings using [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString). This function uses the [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) formatting options.

Now, you can get the value of the seventh column of each row and set a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) i.e. `data-has-link`. You can declare styles for rows i.e. `<td>` with a particular data attribute. This is much easier to work with than abusing classes.

```js
$(function() {
  var $table = $('table');
  $table.find('#current_date').text(getCurrentDate());
  colorRows($table); // Color the rows!
});

function getCurrentDate () {
  return new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric'
  });
}

function colorRows($table) {
  var hasLink;
  $table.find('tbody > tr').each(function(rowIndex) {
    const $row = $(this);
    $row.find('td').each(function(colIndex) {
      const $cell = $(this).removeAttr('data-has-link');
      const cellValue = $cell.text().trim();
      if (isFinite(cellValue)) {
        // Color cell based on individual data
        const hasLink = cellHasLink(parseInt(cellValue, 10));
        if (hasLink !== 'maybe') {
          $cell.attr('data-has-link', hasLink);
        }
      }
    });
    // Color row based on 7th column
    var i = parseInt($row.find('td:nth-child(7)').text(), 10);
    $row.attr('data-has-link', cellHasLink(i));
  });
}

function cellHasLink(value) {
  switch (value) {
    case 0  : return 'no';
    case 1  : return 'yes';
    default : return 'maybe';
  }
}
```

```css
table { width: 20em; border-collapse: collapse; }

th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
}

th:nth-child(n + 2),
td:nth-child(n + 2) {
  text-align: center;
}

[data-has-link="no"]    { background-color: #F77; }
[data-has-link="yes"]   { background-color: #7F7; }
[data-has-link="maybe"] { background-color: #FD7; }

#score, #name {  width: 50%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width: 100%; height:50%" border="1" cellpadding="3">
  <caption>AV.31.U</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="current_date"></div></td>
      <td colspan="6">Home</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Project</th>
      <th>Machine</th>
      <th>te</th>
      <th>Video Link</th>
      <th>te</th>
      <th>File Link</th>
      <th>te</th>
      <th>Draw Link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>22005</td>
      <td>22003652</td>
      <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">Open</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">Open</a></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22012</td>
      <td>22003652</td>
      <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">Open</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">Open</a></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22012</td>
      <td>22003652</td>
      <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">Open</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">Open</a></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### Modifying existing PHP

Modify your PHP to wrap the table header and body appropriately.

```php
<table style="width: 100%; height:50%" border="1" cellpadding="3">
  <caption>AV.31.U</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="current_date">
      <script>
      date = new Date();
      year = date.getFullYear();
      month = date.getMonth() + 1;
      day = date.getDate();
      document.getElementById("current_date").innerHTML = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
      </script></td>
      <td colspan="6">Home</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Проект</th>
      <th>Машина</th>
      <th>te</th>
      <th>video_link</th>
      <th>te</th>
      <th>files_link</th>
      <th>te</th>
      <th>draw_link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    $username = 'censored';
    $password = 'censored';
    $servername = 'censored';
    $database = 'censored';

    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $db = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$servername;Database=$database;", $username, $password) or die ("could not connect<br />");

    $stmt = "Select * from machine";
    $result = odbc_exec($db, $stmt);

    if ($result == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $stmt<br />");

    while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) // while there are rows
    {
      print "<tr>\n";
      print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "project_ID") . "\n";
      print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "machine_project_ID") . "\n";
      print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "video_link") . "\n";
      print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "files_link") . "\n";
      print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "draw_link") . "\n";
      print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, 'has_draw') . "\n";
      print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "has_video") . "\n";
      print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "has_files") . "\n";
      print "</tr>\n";
    }

    odbc_free_result($result);
    odbc_close($db);
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will this work if I get the data from the SQL server?

Comment: @UnixSan the `$('tbody > tr').each` call get run any time the table data is updated.

Comment: Can you help me place your suggestion in my code? Sorry, I am very new to php and jquery.

Comment: @UnixSan I updated the code above to make the functions more obvious. You can keep your PHP as-is. Just fix the `<th>` closing tags and wrap your data rows in a `<tbody>`. The script should work as long as the 7th column is the data you want to assess.

Comment: Now it works, but it also colors the column names and the other row which are on the top. Also is it possible to only color another cell? for example the 6th?

Comment: @UnixSan you need to separate your `<thead>` from your `<tbody>`. Only `<tr>` inside the `<tbody>` should be supplied with background colors.

Comment: Do you happen to know how that can be done? Because the while loop prevents me from separating them.

Comment: @UnixSan Added modified PHP to the end to show how to wrap the `while` loop in a `<tbody>`.

Comment: Thank you so much. And how is it possible to make only a certain cell colored? Is it done by changing the <tr> to <td> in the .css code?

Comment: @UnixSan I will updated the code to show coloring of cells as well. I modified the CSS and dropped the `tr` specificity from the data attribute selector rule.

Comment: I managed to get it running but it colors part of the 3rd row as well. You can even see it here in the post by running the code snippet. Is it possible to only color the cells with the values (1,2,3 for example red,green,yellow)

Comment: @UnixSan yes, just comment out this line only: `$row.attr('data-has-link', cellHasLink(i));`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to add a class with PHP in your while loop.

In your PHP code:

```
$colorclass = [0 => 'red', 1 => 'green', 2 => 'yellow'];
while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) // while there are rows
{
   $classtext = '';
   $x = odbc_result($result, "has_video");
   if( in_array($x, $colorclass) )
   {
      $classtext = " class='".$colorclass[$x]."'";
   }
   print "<tr>\n";
   print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "project_ID") . "\n";
   print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "machine_project_ID") . "\n";
   print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "video_link") . "\n";
   print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "files_link") . "\n";
   print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "draw_link") . "\n";
   print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, 'has_draw') . "\n";
   print "  <td".$classtext.">" . odbc_result($result, "has_video") . "\n";
   print "  <td>" . odbc_result($result, "has_files") . "\n";
   print "</tr>\n";
}
```

In your CSS:

```
.red { background: red; }
.green { background: green; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I put the code you suggested but I do not get any coloring

Comment: Doesn't work is no response... Check your source code. Is the class added in the HTML code? Did you add the CSS? Did you refresh your browser(s cache)?

Comment: I am sorry. I just checked the suggestion of another user and managed to fix my issue. Thank you for your suggestion too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP developer, but if I understand the question right, you want to color the whole table row background if it contains a "0" value to red, "1" value to green, etc.?

In this case you could create a function in php which could add a custom attribute to that specific row like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr my-attribute="0">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr my-attribute="1">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr my-attribute="2">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr my-attribute="1">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and for the css you could easily select this row like this:

```css
tr[my-attribute="0"]{
  background-color: red;
}
tr[my-attribute="1"]{
  background-color: green;
}
tr[my-attribute="2"]{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I want for the code to read the value of a cell and then color either another cell`s background or the whole line.